# Merging and aggregating dataframes using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset, after transformation using Spark Scala (1.6.2). I got the following two dataframes.

DF1:

```
|date | country | count|
| 1872| Scotland|     1|    
| 1873| England |     1|    
| 1873| Scotland|     1|    
| 1875| England |     1|    
| 1875| Scotland|     2|
```

DF2:

```
| date| country | count|
| 1872| England |     1|
| 1873| Scotland|     1|
| 1874| England |     1|
| 1875| Scotland|     1|
| 1875| Wales   |     1|
```

Now from above two dataframes, I want to get aggregate by date per country. Like following output. I tried using union and by joining but not able to get desired results.

Expected output from the two dataframes above:

```
| date| country | count|
| 1872| England |     1|
| 1872| Scotland|     1|
| 1873| Scotland|     2|
| 1873| England |     1|
| 1874| England |     1|
| 1875| Scotland|     3|
| 1875| Wales   |     1|
| 1875| England |     1|
```

Kindly help me get solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to perform an union and then an  groupBy by the two columns, then with the sum, you can specify which column to add up:

```
df1.unionAll(df2)
   .groupBy("date", "country")
   .sum("count")
```

Output:

```
+----+--------+----------+
|date| country|sum(count)|
+----+--------+----------+
|1872|Scotland|         1|
|1875| England|         1|
|1873| England|         1|
|1875|   Wales|         1|
|1872| England|         1|
|1874| England|         1|
|1873|Scotland|         2|
|1875|Scotland|         3|
+----+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the DataFrame API, you can use a `unionAll` followed by a `groupBy` to achive this.

```
DF1.unionAll(DF2)
  .groupBy("date", "country")
  .agg(sum($"count").as("count"))
```

This will first put all rows from the two dataframes into a single dataframe. Then, then by grouping on the date and country columns it's possible to get the aggregate sum of the count column by date per country as asked. The `as("count")` part renames the aggregated column to count.

---

Note: In newer Spark versions (read version 2.0+), `unionAll` is deprecated and is replaced by `union`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me nicely. I was only doing unionAll and i was not getting single dataframe from two somehow. But i missed the groupBy part, But it worked now with your help.